# Samsung gear companion app deep link

Tags: android, tizen, tizen-native-app, samsung-galaxy-gear

I am developing a native (C++) app for Samsung Gear which also uses Android companion app. My app has been rejected due to missing deep link to companion app. I found out that I should include this tag in tizen-manifest.xml

```
<metadata key="master_app_playstore_deeplink" value="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={package_id}"/>
```

However, my app has been rejected again. I get this issue

```
There is no deep link to download companion app '{app name}'
```

with description

```
<Defect>
There is no deep link to download companion app '{app name}'

<Procedure>
1. Check that the app need master app '{app name}'
2. Download the app form Galaxy Apps > Check that no deep link occur

<Expected Result>
DeepLink should occur right after installing Gear application.
<Test Device Info>
Detected Device: SM-N910C_SM-R770, SW Version: R770XXU2BQG4_N910CXXS2DQB8
```

I am not sure how the deep link should work, so I am not able to test it properly.
Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

//EDIT: here is my tizen-manifest.xml (*privileges and features are missing **http://tizen.org/** at the beginning, because I do not have enough rep to post more than two links*)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns="http ://tizen .org/ns/packages" api-version="2.3.2" package="{app_package}" version="1.0.0">
    <profile name="wearable"/>
    <ui-application appid="{app_package}" exec="{exec_name}" multiple="false" nodisplay="false" taskmanage="true" type="capp">
        <label>{app_name}</label>
        <icon>ic_launcher.png</icon>
        <metadata key="accessory-services-location" value="/res/xml/accessoryservices.xml"/>
        <metadata key="launch-on-attach" value="false"/>
        <metadata key="master_app_playstore_deeplink" value="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={package_id}"/>
    </ui-application>
    <privileges>
        <privilege>privilege/mediastorage</privilege>
        <privilege>privilege/appmanager.launch</privilege>
        <privilege>http://developer.samsung.com/tizen/privilege/accessoryprotocol</privilege>
        <privilege>privilege/recorder</privilege>
        <privilege>privilege/externalstorage.appdata</privilege>
        <privilege>privilege/externalstorage</privilege>
    </privileges>
    <feature name="feature/screen.size.all"/>
    <feature name="feature/microphone">true</feature>
</manifest>
```

Comment: give your Android and Tizen Manifest script.

Comment: @Milan did you managed to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The correct URL syntax for deep linking with Play Store is:

```
<metadata key="master_app_playstore_deeplink" value="market://details?id={package_id}"/>
```

See examples for both samsungapps and Play Store under "Notes" in this document: http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/creating-your-first-app/web-companion/configuration

> 1. Samsung Galaxy Apps Guide: Ex) samsungapps://ProductDetail/com.example.myapp
> 2. Play Store Guide :  Ex) market://details?id=com.example.myapp

Please also notice, to make deep linking working, you don't need both URL's, you need only one. I've just submitted my companion app registered at Play Store only, and it works perfectly well with a Gear app.

Comment: I did exactly this in my Tizen .NET companion app, and I was rejected stating there's no deep link to the Android app.

Where is the documentation for how to do this with a .NET Tizen app?

Comment: It's worth noting that your answer, while technically correct, is incomplete. Simply adding the master_app_playerstore_deeplink is not enough to make deep linking from the Tizen companion app to the Play Store work properly. Check the answer here for a full example, specifically tested on a .NET Tizen app: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63678892/1103584

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of `config.xml` taken from a simple Tizen web application, found in the [*Configuring Gear Application* documentation](http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/creating-your-first-app/web-companion/configuration):

> ```
>  <tizen:metadata key="master_app_name" value="master App"/>
>  <tizen:metadata key="master_app_packagename" value="com.example.masterapp"/>
>  <tizen:metadata key="master_app_min_version" value="10"/>
>  <tizen:metadata key="master_app_samsungapps_deeplink" value="Samsungapps deeplink URL"/>
>  <tizen:metadata key="master_app_playstore_deeplink" value="playstore deeplink URL"/>
>  <tizen:metadata key="master_app_3rd_url_deeplink" value="3rd url deeplink URL"/>
>  <name>WebBasic</name>
>  <tizen:profile name="wearable"/>
> ```

and from the [*Samsung Gear Application Programming Guide*](http://blog.tizenappdev.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Samsung_Gear_Application_Programming_Guide.pdf):

> When it comes to determining app priorities in the China model, `master_app_3rd_url_deeplink` is
>   higher than `master_app_samsungapps_deeplink`.
>   In non-China models, `master_app_samsungapps_deeplink` is higher than
>   `master_app_playstore_deeplink`.

So, As you have not given any configuration, i am guessing you have not added `master_app_samsungapps_deeplink`  in your configs.

Comment: As described above you missed the Galaxy apps link in your manifest. It has more priority according to the official document shared by me above. That's why you are getting this message

Comment: He has provided playstore deeplink. Why does he need samsungapps deeplink? You don't need to register your companion in two places. One is sufficient